# Determine whether the first non-space character of #1 is a letter?

Tags: macros, catcodes

Let's say I have a class file with `\title` command, and I want to check that the title starts with a letter, and not with math or a number or a symbol. How can I do that?

This is my MnWE, the syntax of `\@iffirstnotletter` can be of course reasonably modified. If it recognized accented characters as well, it would be a bonus, but it's not necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@iffirstnotletter[3]{#2} % <-- should be modified

\renewcommand\title[1]{\@iffirstnotletter{#1}{%
    \GenericWarning{}{Please start the title with a letter!}%
  }{}%
  \def\@title{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\title{Ahoj}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT:**

My first idea was along the lines of this:

```
\def\ONETWO#1#2\ENDONETWO{#1} % strips the 1st token of
                             % whatever is between `\ONETWO...\ENDONETWO`
\def\@iffirstnotletter#1#2#3{%
  % checks the \catcode of the 1st token of #1 
  \expandafter\ifnum\expandafter\the\expandafter\catcode
    \expandafter`\csname\ONETWO#1\ENDONETWO\endcsname=11\relax
  #3\else#2
\fi}
```

But it has a crazy behaviour for example when the very first thing is `\(` as a beginning of a math-mode: then it gives `! Missing \endcsname inserted.`

Comment: At least for non accented letters `\ifcat` should help

Comment: ah `\ifcat`, ok, seems better than my crazy construct :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A long check with `\futurelet`; this covers UTF-8 multibyte characters, but in the case the first item in the argument is a multibyte character, it will give "good” anyway, as the concept of “UTF-8 letter” is not well defined. On the other hand, this will fail in cases such as “\'{U}jezd”. One could add a list of admissible control sequences for coping with this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifletter[1]{%
  \futurelet\letter@token\checknextletter#1\relax\@nil
}
\def\checknextletter{%
  \ifcat\noexpand\letter@token a%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\@gobbleto@nil{good}}%
  {\checknextutfii}%
}

\def\checknextutfii{%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\UTFviii@two@octets\letter@token
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\@gobbleto@nil{good}}%
  {\checknextutfiii}%
}

\def\checknextutfiii{%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\UTFviii@three@octets\letter@token
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\@gobbleto@nil{good}}%
  {\checknextutfiv}%
}

\def\checknextutfiv{%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\UTFviii@four@octets\letter@token
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\@gobbleto@nil{good}}%
  {\GenericWarning{}{Please start the title with a letter}%
   \@gobbleto@nil{bad}}%
}

\long\def\@gobbleto@nil#1#2\@nil{#1}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb*'foo': \ifletter{foo} = good

\verb*' foo': \ifletter{ foo} = bad

\verb*'f12': \ifletter{f12} = good

\verb*'1oo': \ifletter{1oo} = bad

\verb*'$math$': \ifletter{$math$} = bad

\verb*'\(math\)': \ifletter{\(math\)} = bad

\verb*'äoo': \ifletter{äoo} = good

\verb*'\relax': \ifletter{\relax} = bad

\verb*'': \ifletter{} = bad

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is my try which *seems* to cover the basics:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% I don't want to define \ifdefmacro

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifletter[1]{%
  \ifcat#1a\@empty
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\newcommand\iffirstletter[1]{\@iffirstletter#1\@empty\q@stop}
\def\@iffirstletter#1#2\q@stop{%
  \ifdefmacro{#1}  % to prevent error messages from accented letters, they're false
    {\@secondoftwo}% starts with macro...
    {\ifletter{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

!\iffirstletter{foo}{true}{false}! = true

!\iffirstletter{ foo}{true}{false}! = true

!\iffirstletter{f12}{true}{false}! = true

!\iffirstletter{1oo}{true}{false}! = false

!\iffirstletter{$math$}{true}{false}! = false

!\iffirstletter{\(math\)}{true}{false}! = false

!\iffirstletter{äoo}{true}{false}! = false % this may be misleading

!\iffirstletter{\relax}{true}{false}! = false

!\iffirstletter{}{true}{false}! = false

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\UTFviii@two@octets{...}` is what all UTF characters expand to, but that's not so important now. I can always state in the manual that the warning should be ignored in such cases. I'll, however, wait to see if someone finds a different approach that would solve the other issues, too.

Comment: Ah, yes. I knew that once... One could add a test for that of course. (But wouldn't that then tie a user to utf8 as input encoding (what they should be using anyway)?) Or recommend XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX where accented letters _are_ letters :)

Comment: @tohecz not all characters, just ones that take two octets (some take 3 or 4)